# How to to use the val name of selected element in a chisel Vector in the generated Verilog

Tags: chisel

I'm trying to keep the Val name of a signal in the generated Verilog. The Val is a dynamically  selected element from a chisel Vector(Vec). Below is my test case code:

```
val myVec    = Reg(Vec(10,UInt(32.W)))
val selected = myVec(io.sel).suggestedName("selected")
```

I can see in the generated verilog the Mux that takes the selcted element from myVec. However, it has a random name _T something. `suggestName()` didn't help. I've also tried  `@chiselName`  without any improvement.
The reason I want this signal to have a meaningful name is for debug purposes(functionally it is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, sorry for the confusion/frustration. Glossing over some details, it's difficult for Chisel to tell the difference between a dynamic index as a right-hand value (reading) vs. left-hand value (writing) which makes it hard to name.

You can work around this by connecting the output of a dynamic index to a `Wire`:

```scala
val myVec    = Reg(Vec(10,UInt(32.W)))
val selected = WireInit(myVec(io.sel))
```

The `Wire` will be named via the normal mechanisms so `@chiselName`, `suggestName` or standard reflective naming will work.

Executable example using Chisel v3.3.2: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UWYCtq37ReaVcRrNBxRlOA